# How to use pandas.style with streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit, pandas-styles

I am creating an app with Streamlit and I wish to print out a pandas dataframe in which I can change the background color of each cell of the dataframe. I found out that this is supported by pandas with the package 'pandas.style' but I couldn't make it work with streamlit. I was thus wondering if this is possible with streamlit or if anyone has found a work around.

Here is what I have tried:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: "background-color: red")
st.dataframe(df)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `df.style.apply` or `df.style.applymap` returns a styled dataframe, while you seem to assume that it operates in-place.

Change your code to `st.dataframe(df.style.apply(lambda x: "background-color: red"))` and it should work.